# Why does merging these branches do nothing?

Tags: git, git-merge

**Short version:**

I have two branches with different contents. When I am in one branch and do a merge from the other, it says "Already up-to-date". How is this even possible?

I'm not even doing a pull at this point, just a merge from a local branch, to keep things simple.

**Possibly too much detail follows.**

I'll show one particular file as an example. In branch master (I'm redacting email addresses and older commits):

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

$ git log mde/ss/schools/_clone/segmeta.csv
commit 9e9ee2b19e7a476f2d61ecff1c5d54634132dd93
Author: gormleycep <redacted>
Date:   Mon Nov 23 11:18:41 2015 -0800

    Fixes spacing issues in segmeta files (my mistake)

commit 6e341cd2a92a1044c957a7a9631e365a08466440
Author: gormleycep <redacted>
Date:   Fri Nov 6 12:36:52 2015 -0800

    Updated percent positive tables

commit efc05d8b838fb3e8efdc074b65d1a93046c7e6c9
Author: Alan deLespinasse <redacted>
Date:   Tue Aug 11 18:46:42 2015 -0400

    Fix missing segmentations in MDE Secondary School reports.
```

In branch BTP_E2ESCH:

```
$ git checkout BTP_E2ESCH
Checking out files: 100% (2330/2330), done.
M       common
Switched to branch 'BTP_E2ESCH'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/BTP_E2ESCH'.

$ git log mde/ss/schools/_clone/segmeta.csv
commit 9367a601eef9a7a8975a0cf22d5b49b163a3710c
Author: cepbrian <redacted>
Date:   Fri Nov 13 16:17:49 2015 -0500

    trying to add end to end tests.

commit efc05d8b838fb3e8efdc074b65d1a93046c7e6c9
Author: Alan deLespinasse <redacted>
Date:   Tue Aug 11 18:46:42 2015 -0400

    Fix missing segmentations in MDE Secondary School reports.
```

The change made on Nov 13 by cepbrian is identical to the change made on Nov 6 by gormleycep (both changes added the same two lines to the file). The change made by gormleycep on Nov 23 removed spaces from both of those lines. The file is definitely not the same in the two branches. Now I do:

```
$ git merge master
Already up-to-date.
```

And the file in branch BTP_E2ESCH has not changed.

Here's the output of `gitk --all --date-order mde/ss/schools/_clone/segmeta.csv`, for easier visualization:

[image]

What state can Git be in where this would happen?

Comment: That can happen if you have a tag named `master`, for example. Try `git rev-parse master` and check if it is the expected commit.

Comment: Interesting idea @rodrigo , but `git rev-parse master` returns the commit that I expected (head of the master branch). Also, `git tag` returns nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem it that the output of `git log -- <filename>` can be a bit *deceitful*. From `man git-log`:

> [--] ...
>              Show only commits that are enough to explain how the files that
>              match the specified paths came to be.

And redirects to **History Simplification** section where there are a lot of details...

What I mean is that your branch is probably already merged, but you cannot see that in your simplified logs!

This is best seen with an example. Lets consider this repository:

```
A----B----C----M
     \----T----/
```

Where there are to branches, `test` points to `T` and `master` points to `M`, which is a merge commit. There is one `file` in the repository, with this content at each commit:

```
A: 1
B: 2
C: 3
T: ttt
M: 3
```

When doing the merge of `test` into `master` there was a conflict, and that was solved by discarding the version from `T`.

Now, if I run from `master`, `git log`, I get:

```
M
C
T
B
A
```

But if I run `git log -- file`, I get:

```
C
B
A
```

because the `T` and `M` commits have no effect to the final contents of the file. That's *history simplification*!

You can run `git log --full-history -- test` to get all the commits that touch the file:

```
M
C
T
B
A
```

Comment: I had a feeling it was something like this, and in fact I had been playing with --full-history, but I hadn't managed to find the relevant merge (the number of commits is much higher in my real repo). But also I think my confusion was partly due to wrong expectations about what merge does - I was expecting it to somehow merge in the version of the file from the other branch, even if that version was already an ancestor of my current branch. Of course that doesn't really make sense. Oh well. Thanks!

Comment: I notice that the history you show for `git log` in master is the same as the history you show for `git log --full-history`. Is this correct? Or should the log in master (without --full-history) be `M C B A` (without T)?

Comment: @aldel: I think my logs are correct (a minor typo there, maybe that misleaded you). `git log` lists every commit reachable from `master`, that includes both parents of the merge (`C` and `T`).  The trick is that `--full-history` prevents the history simplification, but HS only happens when there is a path in the command line. Note that I did `git log` and then `git log --full-history -- file`.